# How do I delete the title from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I have around 2,000 text files containing summaries of news articles and I want to remove the title from all the files that have titles (some don't have titles for some reason) using Python.

Here's an example:

```
Ad sales boost Time Warner profit 

Quarterly profits at US media giant TimeWarner jumped 76% to $1.13bn (£600m) for the three months to December, from $639m year-earlier.Its profits were buoyed by one-off gains which offset a profit dip at Warner Bros, and less users for AOL.It lost 464,000 subscribers in the fourth quarter profits were lower than in the preceding three quarters.However, the company said AOL's underlying profit before exceptional items rose 8% on the back of stronger internet advertising revenues.Time Warner's fourth quarter profits were slightly better than analysts' expectations.For the full-year, TimeWarner posted a profit of $3.36bn, up 27% from its 2003 performance, while revenues grew 6.4% to $42.09bn.For 2005, TimeWarner is projecting operating earnings growth of around 5%, and also expects higher revenue and wider profit margins.
```

My question is how to remove the line, "Ad sales boost Time Warner profit" ?

Edit: I basically want to remove everything before a line break.

TIA.

Comment: What does a file without a title look like?  i.e. how would your program be able to tell whether the first line of text in the file is a title versus the first paragraph of the article?

Comment: Do you just want to delete everything that is before a line break?

Comment: It looks like this with a title:   "Title\n\nBody" . Without a title, it just looks like a string, i.e. "Body".

Comment: you might want to edit your question @DeviKrishnan and include an example

Comment: Can "Body" contain "\n\n"?

Comment: @LN_P yes pretty much

Comment: Now you have posted the question can you post your attempt as well

Comment: @fabianegli It shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's (as you say) just a simple matter of removing the first line, when followed by `\n\n`, you could use a simple regex like this:

```
import re

with open('testing.txt', 'r') as fin:
    doc = fin.read()

doc = re.sub(r'^.+?\n\n', '', doc)
```

Comment: Works, but regex seems to me like an overkill for this problem.

Comment: Regex are fast, and designed for exactly this sort of simple text matching/replacement problem. It's a single line of code that does exactly what OP asked. Hardly "overkill".

Comment: only reasonable answer, even if `doc = '\n\n'.join(doc.split('\n\n')[1:])` would be a oneliner, too. without requiring regex.

Comment: I like the clever use of `split`/`join` there. You should add that as an answer, perhaps. I think it's a solid and efficient alternative to my own. However, I do think that it is slightly less readable. It's instantly clear what the regex is doing ("replace pattern OP described with nothing"), whereas even though I'm comfortable with `join`/`split` I had to think about it for a minute to understand why it worked.

Comment: :-D I know, reading and understanding simple regex is easy. but this only applies to people like you and me who actually know regex. feel free to incorporate it as an alternative into into your answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove everything before the first line break (`'\n\n'`).

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    f = file.read()

idx = f.find('\n\n') # Search for a line break
if idx > 0:          # If found, return everything after it
    g = f[idx+2:]
else:                # Otherwise, return the original text file
    g = f

print(g)

# Save the file
with open('text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(g)
```

```
"Quarterly profits at US media giant TimeWarner jumped 76% to $1.13bn (£600m) for the three months to December, from $639m year-earlier.Its profits were buoyed by one-off gains which offset a profit dip at Warner Bros, and less users for AOL.It lost 464,000 subscribers in the fourth quarter profits were lower than in the preceding three quarters.However, the company said AOL's underlying profit before exceptional items rose 8% on the back of stronger internet advertising revenues.Time Warner's fourth quarter profits were slightly better than analysts' expectations.For the full-year, TimeWarner posted a profit of $3.36bn, up 27% from its 2003 performance, while revenues grew 6.4% to $42.09bn.For 2005, TimeWarner is projecting operating earnings growth of around 5%, and also expects higher revenue and wider profit margins.\n"
```

Comment: what you call line break are actually two consecutive line breaks that result in an empty line.

Comment: I agree with you. I was using the language in the question.

Comment: also saving to the same file name warrants a warning that original data will be lost if there is no backup. saving to text-with-no-title.txt would be one possiible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
it will split the text into everything before the line break "\n\n" and only select the last element (the body)

```
line.split('\n\n', 1)[-1]
```

This also works when there is no line break in the text

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, you can't read and write to a file. - Therefore the solution in this case would be to read the lines to a variable; modify and re-write to file.

```
lines = []

# open the text file in read mode and readlines (returns a list of lines)
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# open the text file in write mode and write lines
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    # if the number of lines is bigger than 1 (assumption) write summary else write all lines
    file.writelines(lines[2:] if len(lines) > 1 else lines)
```

The above is a simple example of how you can achieve what you're after. - Although keep in mind that edge cases might be present.

Comment: This one is too specific

Comment: You give people the rod, and teach them how to fish. - The exact solution is close to what is above; and a bit of trivial thought will help him/her learn.